# Which moth is this?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, lepidoptera

City name - Mohali (Chandigarh)
Season - winter(after rain of western disturbance) 
Location - IISER Mohali hostel near tube light of mess
Time - 21:49, 22 February 2019
Size - 1.5cm
[image]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b07dR.jpg):
[image]

Comment: I'll swear it's a hawk moth, which hawk moth is another matter though.

Comment: Providing geographical location is good but it need not go into details which nobody else would be aware of. For example, you should indicate in which part of the world (and country) your location is and what is the general weather/vegetation conditions in that region. Any average person (even an Indian) may not know where Mohali is. You have mentioned about the weather but you should clarify what "western disturbance" is. Now, the specific details about your institute hostel and mess are not relevant unless you have a unique ecosystem. In that case you should explain the local conditions.

Comment: It does look like a gray hawk moth "species" with hind wings folded underneath. The body shape seems right, but the size estimation seems too small.

Comment: It resembles a *Laothoe species*, indeed member of the hawk moth familie. However, all *Laothoe sp* described on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laothoe_(moth)) have a wing span over 7cm and none of them occurs in India.

Comment: It's bombyx mori moth